# Automatic parenthesis visual studio code (reactjs)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

Does different programs behave differently regarding adding automatically parenthesis, even if i dont want to put it, im beginner on reactjs and coding in two different places on visual studio code and https://codesandbox.io, I have a code where it displays three tags (list) the same code on codesandbox has not any error message and work without any problem but on visual studio code( i have disabled all extensions) it automatically adds parenthesis and even if i delete it, it saves it with parenthesis, how to save on visual studio code without it adding automatically parenthesis: here is the code

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0,
    tags: ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
  };

  renderTags() {
    if (this.state.tags.length === 0) return <p> There are no tags!</p>;

    return <ul>{this.state.tags.map(tag => <li key={tag}>{tag} </li>)}</ul>;
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderTags()}</div>;
  }
}
export default Counter;
```

English is not my mother language so sorry for mistakes, here is how it changed my code :

```js
  renderTags() {
    if (this.state.tags.length === 0) return <p> There are no tags!</p>;

    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.tags.map(tag => (
          <li key={tag}>{tag} </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Do you use any code formatter?

Comment: i use Prettier - Code formatter and Simple React Snippets , but as i said i have disabled them.

Comment: impossible, your code is formatted so much

Comment: I see even if i have disabled them, its affecting somehow, now i have uninstalled and its working... dont know why, if i want to use those extensions, how to save my code without those ? parenthesis, cuz its forcing to use them...